# Положение окна WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Окно WPF запускается с WindowState="Maximized". Если сразу после запуска посмотреть   Left или Top окна то они будут равны -8. Собственно вопрос, как получить это значение при выполнении программы? Я так понял они определяются темой. Можно конечно при первом отображении окна запомнить эти значения и использовать, а можно ли как-то по другому это сделать? Через SystemParameters тоже ничего получить не удалось. На скриншоте LiveTree и в диспетчере свойств видно -8. Как добраться до этих значений из кода? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужные значения получаю с помощью GetWindowRect. Можно ли это реализовать без winapi?

Comment: Ну, как вариант забиндить их и считывать, как это должно быть в MVVM.

Comment: а если не секрет, то что вы хотите сделать то?

Comment: По наследству достался проект в котором нельзя менять разметку, но надо сделать аля кнопку пуск справа (адаптация под тач) Сделал меню, отоброжаю его в модальном прозрачном окно поверх основного окна. Всё работает, но есть проблема с определением положения основного окна после того как вышли из режима Maximized и вернулись обратно. Плюс если поменять тему, значение тоже изменится.  Пока получаю через GetWindowRect, либо при первом запуске запоминать эти значения

Comment: Как вариант, повесить обработчики на `LocationChanged`/`SizeChanged` события, и считывать изменения там.